# Conditional Sum For Multiple Datasets in RDLC

Tags: report, rdlc

I'm trying to sum up values based on the 'Description' column of a dataset. So far, I have this

```
=Sum(Cdbl(IIf(First(Fields!Description.Value, "Items") = "ItemA", Sum(Fields!Price.Value, "Items"), 0)))
```

But it keeps giving me an error saying that it "contains a First, Last, or Previous aggregate in an outer aggregate. These aggregate functions cannot be specified as nested aggregates" Is there something wrong with my syntax here?

What I need to do is take something like this...

```
 Item  |  Price
Item A |  400.00
Item B |  300.00
Item A |  200.00
Item A |  100.00
```

And I need to get the summed Price for 'ItemA' - 700.00 in this case.

All of the answers I've found so far only show for a single dataset OR for use with a tablix. For example, the below code does not work because it does not specify the scope or the dataset to use.

```
=Sum(Cdbl(IIf(Fields!Description.Value) = "ItemA", Sum(Fields!Price.Value), 0)))
```

I also can't specify a dataset to use, because the control I'm loading into is a textbox, not a tablix.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else sees this and wants an answer, I ended up returning a count back of what I needed on another dataset. The other option I was thinking would possibly be to create a 1x1 tablix, set the dataset, and then use the second bit of code posted.